# Why does JHipster generate Interfaces for Angular model objects?

Tags: jhipster

Why does JHipster generate interfaces for each Angular model object?

e.g.

```
export interface IStudent {
    id?: number;
    studentIdentifier?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
}

export class Student implements IStudent {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public studentIdentifier?: string,
        public firstName?: string,
        public lastName?: string,
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot find the original discussion but in my understanding, this is because of the way how interfaces work in TypeScript, which is a little different than in Java. They not just describe how a class should look like by defining its method, but also which fields should be present. So you can define, how a JSON from somewhere should look like. Like a POJO. Or a POTO (plain old TypeScript object) :)

By example, you could do that:

```
let student: IStudent = { id: 123, studentIdentifier: '...',...}
```

and TS would check if your provided object satisfies the defined structure of student. When you get an object out from the API, you just map a JSON directly this way, so there is no class in between. From the other side, it's more handy to work with classes rather than interfaces, when building objects of IStudent directly. As it also satisfies IStudent, you can make just

```
let student: IStudent = new Student(123, '...', ..)
```

which is shorter.

You could rely also on my first snippet (this is how ionic does it, btw. Using interfaces as POJOs/POTOs). Using classes only in TS leads to a bad developer experience IMHO.

Hope that helps a little bit out

Comment: Btw, what "TOJO"s stand for?

Comment: POJO = plain old Java object, just an class with fields with getters and setters and no further logic. TOJO would than be the same for TypeScript. But I see my own mistake, it should be POTO/POTSO not TOJO :)